# Is there an App for Browsing on iOS and watching on OS X?

Tags: macos, ios, video, airplay, vlc

I would like to browse video website on my iPhone and start watching videos on my Mac. I don't want to use Airplay as my Wifi connection is not good. I would like to just send an URL to a video player like VLC on my Mac which streams the video itself.

Answer (score 1):

This is the sort of thing that [Handoff](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204681#handoff) (part of [Continuity](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204681)) would ideally be used for, but third-parties have been very slow to adopt it. And you presumably want something better than pasting URLs into the built-in Notes app, with iCloud syncing turned on.

If it's always URLs you want to send, your best bet is possibly a third-party tool for sharing and syncing clipboard items between iOS and Mac, such as [Cloud Clip](http://www.thinkbitz.com/cloudclip/).